# Где хранится информация о знаке числа?

Tags: ассемблер

Разбираюсь с ассемблером.
Хочется понять, где хранится информация о том, что то или иное число (без-)знаковое. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Comment: Если речь о целых числах, то в самом числе. Старший разряд является знаковым (1 - число отрицательное).

См. [Дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29).

Comment: Для целых чисел, на ассемблерном уровне обычно нет информации о том, это число со знаком или без. С битами, составляющими число, можно работать как будто это число со знаком, и как будто это беззнаковое число. Компилятор выбирает подходящие операции основываясь на своей информации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Извиняюсь, наверное, не совсем точно вопрос объяснил. Прекрасно понимаю, что такое дополнительный код. Вопрос как раз заключается в том, хранится ли где-то информация о знаке числа так, чтобы ее различал компилятор, а не только программист. Или в случае с ассемблером, компилятор ничего не знает о знаке?

Comment: Компилятор, когда компилирует код, знает, число знаковое или нет. И если он видит "нужно сложить два знаковых числа", то он просто вставит команду "взять данные по одному адресу, загрузить в регистр, взять по другому и записать в регистр и сложить то, что получилось по правилам складывания знаковых чисел".

Поэтому ответ на Ваш вопрос - если такая информация нужна, компилятор ее для себя сохраняет (например, в виде отладочной информации или специфического набора команд). В общем случае, смотря в скомпилированный код, нельзя уверенно сказать, какая там была переменная.

Comment: Дополню. Нигде не хранится.

Но если целые числа, например, умножаются/делятся как знаковые (imul, idiv), то по идее они должны быть знаковыми. Точно так же, если используются условные операторы, учитывающие знак (js, jg, jge, jl, jle), значит результат последней операции - знаковое число, операнды по идее тоже.
Сложение/вычитание для знаковых (считаем, что отрицательные числа хранятся в дополнительном коде) и беззнаковых чисел не различается.

Comment: @mikeb235, именно команды условных переходов определяют, проводилась ли операция с знаковыми или беззнаковыми числами.

Небольшой пример:

      int a = 10, b = -10; unsigned ua = a, ub = b;
    
      if (a > b)
        printf ("%d > %d\n", a, b);
      if (ua > ub)
        printf ("%u > %u\n", ua, ub);

    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc -S c.c

            movl    $10, 16(%esp)  // a = 10
            movl    $-10, 20(%esp) // b = -10
            movl    16(%esp), %eax
            movl    %eax, 24(%esp) // ua = a
            movl    20(%esp), %eax
            movl    %eax, 28(%esp) // ub = b

Comment: продолжение (места-то в комментриях мало)

    .... 
            movl    16(%esp), %eax
            cmpl    20(%esp), %eax // if cmp(a, b)
            jle     .L2            // a <= b
            movl    20(%esp), %eax 
            movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
            movl    16(%esp), %eax
            movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
            movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
            call    printf
    .L2:
            movl    24(%esp), %eax
            cmpl    28(%esp), %eax // if cmp(ua, ub)
            jbe     .L3            // ua <= ub
     ....

см. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о целых числах, то в самом числе. Старший разряд является знаковым (1 - число отрицательное). См. [Дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)). *-- @avp*

Для целых чисел, на ассемблерном уровне обычно нет информации о том, это число со знаком или без. С битами, составляющими число, можно работать как будто это число со знаком, и как будто это беззнаковое число. Компилятор выбирает подходящие операции основываясь на своей информации. *-- @VladD*

Компилятор, когда компилирует код, знает, число знаковое или нет. И если он видит "нужно сложить два знаковых числа", то он просто вставит команду "взять данные по одному адресу, загрузить в регистр, взять по другому и записать в регистр и сложить то, что получилось по правилам складывания знаковых чисел". Поэтому ответ на Ваш вопрос - если такая информация нужна, компилятор ее для себя сохраняет (например, в виде отладочной информации или специфического набора команд). В общем случае, смотря в скомпилированный код, нельзя уверенно сказать, какая там была переменная. *-- @KoVadim*

На ассемблерном уровнем определить, являются ли числа знаковыми, можно по выполняемым над ними операциям. Например, если целые числа умножаются/делятся как знаковые (`imul`, `idiv`), то по идее они должны быть знаковыми. Точно так же, если используются условные операторы, учитывающие знак (`js`, `jg`, `jge`, `jl`, `jle`), значит результат последней операции - знаковое число, операнды по идее тоже. Сложение/вычитание для знаковых (считаем, что отрицательные числа хранятся в дополнительном коде) и беззнаковых чисел не различается. *-- @insolor*

Именно команды условных переходов определяют, проводилась ли операция с знаковыми или беззнаковыми числами. Небольшой пример:

Фрагмент файла c.c:

```
int a = 10, b = -10;
unsigned ua = a, ub = b;
if (a > b) printf ("%d > %d\n", a, b);
if (ua > ub) printf ("%u > %u\n", ua, ub);
```

Компиляция в ассемблерный код:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc -S c.c
```

Результат:

```
movl $10, 16(%esp) // a = 10
movl $-10, 20(%esp) // b = -10
movl 16(%esp), %eax
movl %eax, 24(%esp) // ua = a
movl 20(%esp), %eax
movl %eax, 28(%esp) // ub = b
movl 16(%esp), %eax
cmpl 20(%esp), %eax // if cmp(a, b)
jle .L2 // a <= b

movl 20(%esp), %eax
movl %eax, 8(%esp)
movl 16(%esp), %eax
movl %eax, 4(%esp)
movl $.LC0, (%esp)
call printf
.L2: movl 24(%esp), %eax
cmpl 28(%esp), %eax // if cmp(ua, ub)
jbe .L3 // ua <= ub
....
```

Cм. [Wikibooks: X86 Assembly/Control Flow](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) *-- @avp*

*Ответ сформирован из комментариев @avp, @VladD, @KoVadim, @insolor под вопросом.*